# Is there any way I can get Scrybe (Gesture Workflow Technology)?

Tags: software-recommendation, touchpad

[Scrybe](http://www.uscrybe.com/index.php) is a program powered by [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/) for Touch pad to use it like Gesture Workflows.

[image]

Is there any way that I can use it in Ubuntu? If not, is there an equivalent software ready to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrybe provides only .exe, no word about supporting X server. But there are maybe few possibilities, found on 
http://alternativeto.net/software/scrybe/?platform=linux

easystroke looks good, but havent tried it personally
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CagAEgXAAzA

Comment: I am using easystroke. Since 11.04 it works fine. In scrype you start the gesture with a three finger tip, in easystroke you have to assign a button. I use left mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

This link will answer your query

[SOLVED] Scrybe Gesture Workflows for ubuntu using easystroke

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836089&highlight=scrybe

Comment: It's preferable if you don't just post a link solving the problem. If you write out the steps it really helps the asker and others who come here.